# How To Get style= background-img URL Using Cheerio

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js, cheerio

I'm trying to get the URL of the background image. The background image is in the a href tag.

a href tag, `style="background-img:url("")"`

I'm using cheerio (node.js modules similar to Jquery). While I try to get
It gives me error of,

**TypeError: Cannot Read Property "replace" for undefined**

My Code Is:

```
$("div.listing.listing-blog.listing-blog-1.clearfix.columns-1.columns-1 > article > .item-inner  .featured.clearfix  a").map(function () {
    let imgURL = $(this).css("background-image");
    imgURL = imgURL.replace(/.*\s?url\([\'\"]?/, '').replace(/[\'\"]?\).*/, '');
    return { imgURL };
  }).get();
```

This Is The Element, From which the URL of background Image is needed:

```
<article class="post-431236 type-post format-standard has-post-thumbnail   listing-item listing-item-blog  listing-item-blog-1 main-term-51 bsw-5 ">
<div class="item-inner clearfix">
<h2 class="title"> <a href="https://arynews.tv/en/nab-money-laundering-reference-shehbaz-sharif/" class="post-url post-title">
POST TITLE </a>
</h2>
<div class="featured clearfix">
<a alt="nab, shehbaz sharif, pml-n, benami assets" title="NAB prepares money-laundering reference against Shehbaz Sharif: sources" data-bs-srcset="{&quot;baseurl&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/arynews.tv\/wp-content\/uploads\/2020\/09\/&quot;,&quot;sizes&quot;:{&quot;210&quot;:&quot;shehbaz-1-1-210x136.jpg&quot;,&quot;279&quot;:&quot;shehbaz-1-1-279x220.jpg&quot;,&quot;357&quot;:&quot;shehbaz-1-1-357x210.jpg&quot;,&quot;750&quot;:&quot;shehbaz-1-1.jpg&quot;}}" class="img-holder    b-loaded" href="https://arynews.tv/en/nab-money-laundering-reference-shehbaz-sharif/" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://arynews.tv/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/shehbaz-1-1-279x220.jpg&quot;);"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the jQuery so are you sure the selector is right? Can you show us the CSS for the element?

Comment: *cannot read property for undefined* - simply add a clause, something like `let imgURL = $(this).css("background-image") || "";`

Comment: I'm using Cheerio it's similar to Jquery. But I'm getting Undefined.

Answer (score 5):

cheerio doesn't have those methods, you need to use attr():

```
// untested, I have no idea what your element looks like
$(a).attr('style').match(/url\("(.*?)"/)[1]
```

Comment: Thankyou so much! I tried but it didn't worked. Although, I have added the element, check above. I need the background image URL, which is in style.

Comment: This worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using pure `js` without `jQuery` you can type:

```
const selector = `div.listing.listing-blog.listing-blog-1.clearfix.columns-1.columns-1 > article > .item-inner  .featured.clearfix  a`;

const imgURL = document.querySelector(selector).style.background
```

You will receive string like

```
"url("http://localhost:1337/uploads/offline_reset_45146034ad.jpg") center center no-repeat"
```

Next step is get URL from this string by regex.

And your example:

```
imgURL.replace(/.*\s?url\([\'\"]?/, '').replace(/[\'\"]?\).*/, '')
```

works great giving

```
"http://localhost:1337/uploads/offline_reset_45146034ad.jpg"
```

Comment: Its Returning me imgURL=''
What Shall I do?

Comment: show `document.querySelector(selector).innerHTML` and paste it to your question

Comment: I have added the element, above in the question. Check it, I want to get the img URL. Which is in style background img url